# clang-format: designated initializer: One member per line

Tags: c, clang, clang-format

I have a struct in C:

```c
struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

When initializing the struct clang-format reformats the code as follows:

```c
struct A name = {.a = 1, .b = 2, .c = 3};
```

How can I tell clang-format to put any member in its own line? Like so:

```c
struct A name = {
    .a = 1,
    .b = 2,
    .c = 3
};
```

Comment: I believe adding a trailing comma fixes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a trailing comma should fix this problem.

```c
struct A name = {
    .a = 1,
    .b = 2,
    .c = 3, // <-- this trailing comma is needed
};
```